# XPath XML search root node for match, ignoring children

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG YEAR="1988">
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <VINYL>
    <TITLE>Seventh Son of a Seventh Son</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Iron Maiden</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </VINYL>
</CATALOG>
```

In the above xml file, I want to check that the year of the Catalog is 1987, 1988, or 1989. However, when I use my search below

> //CATALOG[matches(@YEAR, "198[789]")]

I get a match on both the Catalog year and the year of Seventh Son of a Seventh Son. How can I search only the root node? I tried searching with "self" or "." with no success. Thanks

Comment: The expression is not selecting the `VINYL` node containing "Seventh Son...".  It is selecting the _entire_ `CATALOG` node because the regular expression is matching CATALOG's `YEAR` attribute.  You cannot use XPath to select a node without its children and you cannot use XPath to select both a node and a subset of its children.  As already suggested XSLT, XQuery or some other programmatic construct is needed to achieve selecting a node without (or with a subset of) its descendants.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is a correct XPath-2.0 expression. So a valid XSLT-2.0 stylesheet could look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="//CATALOG[matches(@YEAR, '198[789]')]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet matches and copies all root elements (probably one) with the given condition. Your expression is correct.

And if this doesn't work as desired, just use

```
/CATALOG[matches(@YEAR, '198[789]')]
```

This will (for sure) select the root element with the given properties.